# How to prevent the need for importing a framework in each class?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, pch

I have a framework called Parse, which is used in almost each Viewcontroller that I have. How can I prevent the need to put an import statement in each class, like #import Parse/Parse.h
??

I heard you should include it in the PCH file, but somehow that doesn't work. Do I need to set the PCH in 'compile sources', or something like that?

Comment: You should already have a file called `NameOfMyProject-Prefix.pch`. Add it to that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefix headers are compiled and stored in a cache, and then automatically included in every file during compilation. This can speed up compilation, and lets you include a file without adding an import statement to every file using it.

Example:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
  #import "Constants.h"
#endif
```

Add it in your NameOfMyProject-prefix.pch file.